# Angular bind table to generic object

Tags: javascript, html, .net, angularjs, model-view-controller

I'm just starting to explore with Angular. Now what I'm trying to do is using an mvc handler that returns a jsonobject. However the returned jsonobject is generic, so it can be different types of object, and they all have a different amount of columns. I want to bind all these columns to a table, but that means i can't just create a fixed amount of columns and bind them like so:

```
<table class="table">
            <tr ng-repeat="r in items">
                <td>{{r.ID}}</td>
                <td>{{r.Name}}</td>
                <td>{{r.FirstName}}</td>
                <td>{{r.Telephone}}</td>
                <td>{{r.Email}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

this is NOT the way i want it, basically i want to  have a table that binds to an object and that creates table columns for every property of the object.

thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate the properties of the value like

```
<tr ng-repeat="r in items">
  <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in r">
    {{ value }}
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Here is a fiddle that proves the answer: http://jsfiddle.net/consultwithmike/0rjq726g/

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Thanks Michael, you rock!

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud that's not correct, that only works for 1 object, not for an object list. But Rebornix' answer is correct! That worked fine, thanks so much :)

Comment: @WtFudgE, obviously. It's clearly not complex to extrapolate a loop right? The point was I had a working example for the object and it supports this answer.